# CSS one regular animation one looping animation NO JS

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

How can I play keyframes 0%-50% then loop continually from 50%-100% ? I know this is possible by adding / removing a class from the div but I'd like to do this without javascript.

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

@keyframes divReady {
  0% { width: 0vmin; }
  50% { width: 20vmin; transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

#the-div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40vmin;
  left: 40vmin;
  width: 0vmin;
  height: 20vmin;
  background: orange;
  animation: divReady 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="the-div">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider two animations. One with `forwards` and the infinite one with a delay equal to the duration of the first one:

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

@keyframes divReady-one {
  0% { width: 0vmin; }
  100% { width: 20vmin; }
}

@keyframes divReady-two {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

#the-div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40vmin;
  left: 40vmin;
  width: 0vmin;
  height: 20vmin;
  background: orange;
  animation: 
    divReady-one 1s forwards,
    divReady-two 2s 1s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div id="the-div">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this within one keyframes you could use two keyframes and two DIV elements see below.

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

@keyframes ani1 {
  0% { width: 0vmin; }
  100% { width: 20vmin; }
}

@keyframes ani2 {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

#div1 {
  top: 40vmin;
  left: 40vmin;
  width: 20vmin;
  height: 20vmin;
  position: absolute;
  animation: ani2 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

#div2 {
  width: 20vmin;
  height: 20vmin;
  background: orange;
  animation: ani1 1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
<div id="div2">
</div>
</div>
```